# Do people in non-Christian cultures use swear words related to the dominant religion?

Tags: comparative-religion

As I'm sure you're aware, people in English-speaking Christian countries often use the words "God" and "Jesus" or other Bible-related words like "damn" and "Hell" as swear words.

Do people in non-Christian cultures use words from their own religions as swear words? Like, if someone in a Muslim country bumps his head does he say "Mohammed damn it!"? Do Buddhists who lose something say, "Oh, Nirvana!"? Or whatever.

I'm just curious whether the idea of using "religious words" as swear words is something unique to Christian cultures, or is found in the cultures of other religions.

Comment: While the question is somewhat interesting, it's not about Christianity, but rather, other religions. Thus, I closed it as off-topic. That said, I don't know of a place where you could ask this question other than in various religious chat rooms ([Christianity](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room), [Judaism](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam), [Islam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3819/islam))

Comment: No. Where religious imagery is invoked at all (not a universal thing) the Christian God and his Christ are a fairly ubiquitous dumping ground.

Comment: Try asking this on Islam.SE.

Comment: Hmm, I'm asking for a comparison between Christianity and other religions. If it's not appropriate to compare Christianity to, say, Islam on a Christian forum, then by the same reasoning it would be inappropriate to compare Islam to Christianity on a Muslim forum, etc, and the question is rendered unaskable. I specifically said in my question that I am seeking to know whether this phenomenon is "unique to Christian cultures". That was the purpose of my question.

Comment: So, maybe this isn't the place to ask it (since the question has been closed), but that is a great question.  I wonder that too.

Comment: Coming from a non-western, buddhist background, in our cultures too these types of swear words exist. They may refer to for example Buddha. To prove that you are telling the truth someone would say "I swear on the Buddha". However, they are not as commonly used as in western countries in the everyday language. Also I am not very sure of the origin of these terms. Maybe they closely relate to my culture associating with non-native ones in the past.